# How to use Django templating inside Angular 2 template?

Tags: python, django, typescript, angular

I am trying to iterate through a django object rendered to an HTML page by the view.
I defined an Angular 2 component in the following manner :-

```
@Component({

selector: 'search',
template:`

            <form [ngFormModel]="form" >
                  {% for category in categories_all %}
                  <li>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                      <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="category" 
                        id="category_{{category.id}}" 
                        value="{{category.name}}"
                        ngControl = "category"
                        #category="ngForm"
                        {% ifequal category.id|stringformat:"s"
                        param_values.category_id|stringformat:"s" %}
                         checked="checked"
                         {% endifequal %}
                         (click)="onClick()">
                 {{category.name}}
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </li>{% endfor %}
            </form>
`,
providers:[ HTTP_PROVIDERS]


})
```

`{% for category in categories_all %}` is django templating syntax so angular2 is not identifying it. Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: You should call `categories` using `ngServices` and store data an array inside `ngModel`.

Comment: Even I thought of doing that but how do I get the categories object? there is no explicit api call for it. when the page is rendered I am passing it as a context.

Comment: Use your Django template to define a javascript var, then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should define your own template tags like this

AngularJS module (app.js)

```
angular.module('myapp', []).config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});
```

Webpage

```
<a>[[ variable ]]</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `{% verbatim %}` Django template tag and put your AngularJS template code between `{% verbatim %}` and `{% endverbatim %}`.

Comment: This works if I am trying to show angular stuff in Django template. What I want to implement is just the opposite.

Comment: Do you want to generate Django templates in the browser using Angular 2 and send those to be parsed by the server?

Comment: Yes. Like I have shown in the code snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

You can get both django and angular2 template working without any conflicts.

If you are using **Jinja2**,  then you can easily change the variable start string in Jinja2 options.

Refer my [blog post](https://4sw.in/blog/2016/django-angular2-tutorial-part-2/) for more details.